# Can not understand why Hbase not A in CAP

Tags: hbase

I read a document said that Hbase is Consistency and Partition in `CAP` theory.

But I can not understand why Hbase is not A? I think Hbase can always keep service available, so why not A?

My understanding of Hbase NOT A: When one new row was inserted into Hbase, because Hbase is immediate consistent, it needs to wait HDFS finish the 3 replicas, but during this replica sync time the new row can not be seen, that's why Hbase is not A. But I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Possibly because of a Master, which is a single point of failure...?

Comment: And it takes some time to recover from a failed region server, during which the regions are not available.

Comment: thanks you guys answer: I'm wondering the reason not A is that: When one row inserted into Hbase, because Hbase is immediate consistency, it needs to wait HDFS finish the 3 replicas, but during this sync time the new row can not be seen, that why Hbase is not A. But I'm not sure about this.

Comment: HBase and HDFS do not wait for the replicas. Fortunately otherwise the system would be extremely slow and unusable! 
As explained by shay__, if a region server is falling down it will take some time for other region servers to take the ownership of the failed regions and make data available again.

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking, a CP system means that when 'network partition' happened, the system will try to ensure consistency (or 'linearizability' from some blogs) instead of making the system 'available'.

Network partition essentially means that the cluster is partitioned to two or more parts and they can't communicate with each other due to network failures. During the time of this network issue, if a write request was made to one side of the cluster (a region server), the system will not accept the write until the issue is resolved. Thus this essentially make the system not really 'available' when network partition happened. In HBase, network partition can result in region in transition and those regions affected will not be able to accept read/write. This is the reason why some post may consider HBase as a CP system. For a system favoring availability, read will not be blocked when system is in a partitioned state.

In real world, availability in CAP has a very specific meaning. It's slightly different from our general meaning of being available. In case of a small network partition, if a quorum based system can quickly remove the bad portion of the cluster from the system, it is possible to ensure consistency while only having a brief period of down time like seconds (or potentially even smaller). So they can still be considered available in general term because they quickly recovered from the failure. But in strict term, if you want to be consistent during a network partition, you will need to wait for the issue to be resolved before you can serve other read requests (and thus not available).

Answer (score 1):

HBase is not avaliable in case when some RegionServer fails. HMaster need some time:

1. to reassign crashed Regions to an active RegionServers.
2. to replay the WAL file to recover the data edits which were kept in MemStore
   (in RAM) of the failed RegionServer.

During this time the Regions corresponding to the failed RegionServer are unavalible. 
See also "HBase crash recovery" [here](https://mapr.com/blog/in-depth-look-hbase-architecture/).

Answer (score 0):

Like Mongo, Hbase also follows leader and replica concept, as per CAP when partitioned, Mongo can be consistence or available. if Master node is down then it will be "consistent' as no more writes are happening, but if other nodes are down then its "available' as consistency will go off as some node are out of sync from master. In this case Hbase also should follow the same.